# making link short in django pagination

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

I have **multiple params** in `GET` request which i'm passing through-out pagination.(i mean pass params in pagination's link).

Following code in my pagination link.

```
        <!-- For the 1st page we do not use ?page=1 -->
        {% if num == 1 %}
            <a class="waves-effect page-link" href="?page={{ num }}{% if search == none %}{%else%}&search={{search}}{%endif%}{% if filter_property == none%}{% else %}&filter_property={{filter_property}}{% endif %}{% if overseas %}&overseas={{overseas}}{% endif %}{% if rtc %}&rtc={{rtc}}{% endif %}{% if rbc %}&rbc={{rbc}}{% endif %}" onclick="quotationPagination(this)">{{ num }}</a>
        {% else %}
        <!-- Show current page and +-3 pages -->
             {% if num|add:"-3" == quotation.number %}
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" data-category="{{request.session.current_category}}" data-page="{{ num }}">
                    <a class="waves-effect page-link">...</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% if num|add:"-2" <= quotation.number and quotation.number <= num|add:"2" %}
                <a class="waves-effect page-link " href="?page={{ num }}{% if search == none %}{%else%}&search={{search}}{%endif%}{% if filter_property == none%}{% else %}&filter_property={{filter_property}}{% endif %}{% if overseas %}&overseas={{overseas}}{% endif %}{% if rtc %}&rtc={{rtc}}{% endif %}{% if rbc %}&rbc={{rbc}}{% endif %}" onclick="quotationPagination(this)">{{ num }}</a>
                <!-- Shows every 10th page and the last page -->
            {% elif num == quotation.paginator.num_pages %}
                <a class="waves-effect page-link " href="?page={{ num }}{% if search == none %}{%else%}&search={{search}}{%endif%}{% if filter_property == none%}{% else %}&filter_property={{filter_property}}{% endif %}{% if overseas %}&overseas={{overseas}}{% endif %}{% if rtc %}&rtc={{rtc}}{% endif %}{% if rbc %}&rbc={{rbc}}{% endif %}" onclick="quotationPagination(this)">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if num|add:"3" == quotation.number %}
                </li>
                <li class="page-item" data-category="{{request.session.current_category}}" data-page="{{ num }}">
                    <a class="waves-effect page-link">...</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </li>
```

have any easy way to implement below **Anchor** link in short ???

```
<a class="waves-effect page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if search == none %}{%else%}&search={{search}}{%endif%}{% if filter_property == none%}{% else %}&filter_property={{filter_property}}{% endif %}{% if overseas %}&overseas={{overseas}}{% endif %}{% if rtc %}&rtc={{rtc}}{% endif %}{% if rbc %}&rbc={{rbc}}{% endif %}" aria-label="Next"> Next</a>
```

is there any solution where i can make it **short** and batter through pythonic way? right now i m using this in multiple place in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django has customized function [urlencode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlencode) or eventually [urlencode filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-urlencode) which can serialize a dictionary into a querystring (eg. `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}` -> `foo=1&bar=2`. Use one of these.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko  what happen if i pass empty string like this ``` {"foo":""} ``` because some value not applied by user so it will be empty. so key will be displayed in url with none or blank?

Comment: I'm afraid that's up to you to find out. In worst case you can filter that dictionary for (non)empty values before serializing.